# How can I change a Tableau data source used by multiple workbooks from live to extract?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau server with 5 data sources. I have 15 workbooks that use the data sources. Today the data sources have live connections to the back-end databases. I want to use extracts instead of live connections, in order to reduce traffic on the databases. How can I change a Tableau data source used by multiple workbooks from live to extract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Tableau Desktop,

1. Connect to the published data source on Tableau Server
2. Create a local copy of the data source (right click on the data source to seen that option)
3. Make whatever changes you wish to the local data source, including creating an extract
4. Publish the revised data source to Tableau Server replacing the original published data source.